# is a page redirect to most current article bad from an seo perspective?

Tags: redirect, seo

I have navigation at the top of my site that links to `news/`

The news is always paginated, one article per page, with the ability to navigate to the next or previous article.

I would like the default article to be the second-to-last most current article.  So if there are 10 articles, when the user clicks on `news/`, they are redirected to `news/9` with 302 redirect code.

From an SEO perspective, is it bad to be constantly redirecting like this?  Would it be better to change the link in the top navigation to instead link directly to `news/9`, and keep changing that everytime there is a new article instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search engines expect a given piece of content to have a canonical URL. It's OK to have any number of URLs to a single page but use a canonical URL.

Sop no matter what redirect you have, add a canonical URL and search engine will take care of any mess.

302 redirects are for this. Use it.

Comment: So as long as I have `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/news/:id_of_article" />` on my redirected destination page I'm fine?  Ok, thanks!

Comment: Yes. But make sure you always keep the URL same with that content. Good luck!